# I get (remote rejected) error when I try to push my app to heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I'm trying to push my backend to heroku for my fullstack app but when I typed "git push heroku master" on my terminal, I get this error

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/ammans-sign-in-backend.git'
```

The video I was following got this error too but he solved it by removing yarn from his package.json. but I don't have yarn installed so I don't know what's causing this error.

full error for reference

```
PS C:\Users\Amman\dunder-mifflin\src\backend> git push heroku master       
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 841 bytes | 420.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 3aa4f9300d4b24e64213357cadb3c360dbff848c
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 3aa4f9300d4b24e64213357cadb3c360dbff848c
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to ammans-sign-in-backend.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/ammans-sign-in-backend.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/ammans-sign-in-backend.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the error, you can see you haven't selected a buildpack. So just go to the website and select the buildpack for the language you are working with.

Comment: I did that but now I'm getting this error   ```ERROR: Application not supported by 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack``` and   ```The 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack is set on this application, but was unable to detect a Node.js codebase. ```